# Admob "request pin" new address is not working

Tags: admob

I had applied for **admob pin verification** once and after sending that I figured that address was wrong so I had updated my new address, and when am trying apply new pin it is still showing the old address. Also I have qualified for the payment threshold.

It has already been 2 weeks nothing came to know. Can anyone help

Answer (score 1):

It can take anywhere from 3weeks to about 8 weeks for you to get your new pin. This is put in place by Google to deter people from constantly changing their addresses just do shady business.
Here is more info directly from google's site: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/157667?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for reply steffan. but i am not asking about pin. i am asking about i want my pin to my new address. but while requesting a new pin admob still showing up the old address. i already updated my address 2 weeks.

Comment: It goes back to the same point, their system is mostly automated, that prevents people from changing their address too often. It's difficult because you seem like you haven't done anything wrong but some people would abuse the system if they were allowed to change their addresses then have it updated faster, it'll take another 2 - 4 weeks for the system to update the records and show the new address.  Hopefully this helped you, if so you can accept the answer.

Comment: okay thank you very much. I'll wait for next payment cycle and will let you know. Hope this time it works

Comment: @krishnakanth I have the same issue? Do you have any new information?

Comment: Me too having same issue :(
Any one here ?

Comment: Me too. I'm facing the same issue. Someone has the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old but I had the same problem today.
You should **log out from your account and clear your cookies**. I was able to send the PIN to my new address immediately with this method.

Hope it helps someone!